# Convert simple_form tag to bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I have this simple postgres search form that I got from railscasts:

```
    %h2
        Search textbook title or ISBN
    = simple_form_for books_path, method: :get do
        = search_field_tag :query, params[:query]
        = submit_tag "Search", name: nil
```

and this bootstrap search form(in haml):

```
.featurette
.featurette-inner.text-center
    %form.search{:role => "form"}
        %h3.no-margin-top.h1 Search Me.
        .input-group.input-group-lg
            %input.form-control{:placeholder => "search", :type => "search"}
                %span.input-group-btn
                    %button.btn.btn-primary{:type => "submit"} Search
```

I would like for the "search_field_tag to become the "input.form-control" and the "submit_tag" to become the "button.btn.btn-primary".

Need your help in combining these two as I am not able to make the search and the submit button to work. Just started rails in like 2 weeks. Any support is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at [simple_form-bootstrap](http://simple-form-bootstrap.plataformatec.com.br/)?

Comment: looking at it right now. will get back with you in a moment

Answer (score 0):

@Jon I still don't understand most of what I'm doing and using f.input as opposed to =search_field_tag just gives me an error. I was able to make it work though. Below is what I used:

```
.featurette
.featurette-inner.text-center
    %form.search{:role => "form"}
        %h3.no-margin-top.h1 Search Me.
        = simple_form_for books_path, method: :get do   
            .input-group.input-group-lg 
                = search_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: "form-control"
                %span.input-group-btn
                    = submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-success"
```